# regexp how to match unknown number of words

Tags: regex

I'm trying to learn regular expressions.
I want to write a regular exprssion that matches an unknown number of words like Martin Arguello (ARG)
I think I can write it like this /\w+\s\w+\s(\w+)/ but I also want to make it work for Martin Vassallo Arguello (ARG) without duplicating that code (so i can extend it easy)?
I have tried to solve it with this /(\w+\s+){2,}(\w+)/, but it didn't help.

Thanks in advance and kind regards,
lerak

Answer (score 0):

I think this RegExp is what you looking for:

```
(\w+\s)+\(\w+\)
```

Comment: yes, that one works, I think the one I had also might be oke. I just found a mistake in a file that I was using. I think that was causing all the trouble. Thanks a lot!